# FCA and PCA vs. Requirements

Tags: design, requirements-management

I was thinking that a Functional Configuration Audit (FCA) point to the Functional Requirements while the Physical Configuration Audit (PCA) is more related to the non Functional Requirements is this true? does anybody has experience doing those audits?

Comment: I haven't heard of the terms FCA and PCA before. A cursory search makes me think these are more related to manufacturing, and the software required to complete the manufacturing process. I guess it could be applied to software projects that have some sort of physical manifestation, like printing a check or sending a postal letter?

Comment: you can find those terms in the swebook, as part of software verification

Answer (score 2):

The mapping of functional configuration audit -> functional requirements and physical configuration audit -> non-functional requirements (or quality attributes) isn't quite right.

A functional configuration audit is a confirmation that the software has been appropriately verified against the requirements, both functional and non-functional. This would look at the requirements, the traceability to design and implementation artifacts, and evidence of verification. For critical systems that require it, there would also be an examination of the verification done with independence.

The physical configuration audit compares the built software system to all of the deliverable documentation artifacts. This is a pretty broad topic. One aspect ensures that the verified software is the version of software delivered (for example, made available for download or burned onto a CD-ROM) or installed (for example, on a delivered computer). There's also an examination of any user manuals or guidance for people performing installations and troubleshooting along with any delivered architectural and design descriptions.

The terms do tend to make more sense if you think about physical systems (that may or may not include software), but some environments have continued to use them for software. Functional is about how the thing functions (including characteristics like performance, and would extend to things like security and usability for software) and physical is about the system being used in its environment by the end-users.